# Polymer 1.0 paper-menu get selected item list

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

menu of polymer 1.0.
I want to get the selected item list when the user click on the menu. 
From what I have read in the doumentation, the IronMultiSelectableBehavior  behavior shall add the selectedItems properties to the paper-menu API
but the properties is undefined when I want to access it.

```
<paper-menu id="messageTypesMenuId" multi on-tap="_onMenuTap" >
    <paper-item role="menuitem">All</paper-item>
    <paper-item role="menuitem">TEst1</paper-item>
    <paper-item role="menuitem">Test2</paper-item>
</paper-menu>

_onMenuTap: function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.selectedItems);
    console.log(this.$.messageTypesMenuId.selectedItems);
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using selectedItems should be fine. However, when the tap event is fired, the selection has not been updated yet. I don't know of a general selection-changed event for the paper menu, but you could use on-iron-select and on-iron-deselect instead. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30633737) also uses these events and may help you.